# test live connect application without a paid developer account

Tags: windows-runtime, windows-store-apps, onedrive, c++-cx, live-connect-sdk

[similar question was asked here on msdn](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/live/en-US/aa905503-1ae2-45df-af6b-a8eabda37391/testing-live-connect-sdk-in-a-windows-store-app-without-a-store-account?forum=messengerconnect)

I recently started learning Windows Store Application development using c++/cx. I got a developer account(just singed in with my outlook account when visual studio asked for a developer account) and could test most of the application i created on my Windows 8.1 PC.

I am now creating a sample application for reading SkyDrive's content for the signed-in user and displaying it on the screen. To be able to login to a Microsoft account i need to associate my sample application with Windows Store which requires a paid developer account. I had tested a similar sample app in Android which didn't require any such registration. I am wondering if there is any workaround which wouldn't require me to buy a paid developer account as i don't intend to publish any application on the store but merely want to test the Live API.

Also, if not then Why would Microsoft want the developers to pay for just testing the Apps they create which they might or might not finally submit to the Windows Store?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an alternative.Just download one of Microsoft's Official Sample Apps for Windows 8.1(Samples are available in C++, C#, VB and JavaScript) and modify it. The Sample Apps are already associated with Windows Store and hence would let you login to a Microsoft Account using the built-in login mechanism.

Answer (score 0):

The only way (I think) is to register [App here](https://account.live.com/developers/applications) and create not a Windows Store app, but classic Windows App. So, code base will be mostly the same. LiveSdk have no choice to set app Id or app secret in Windows Store version of Live Sdk. Alternatively, there is an ability to get free dev account via [dreamspark](https://www.dreamspark.com/) or [bizspark](http://www.microsoft.com/bizspark/default.aspx), but there some requirements.